# React antd Upload input required error with default list

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use `antd` UI framework on my app. Also, I have `form` with the required `Upload` image field. Sometimes this field has `defaulList`. Problem is that still validation is not passed when `defaultList` is defined.

`Upload` props:

```
const uploadProps = {
    name: 'file',
    action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
    headers: {
      authorization: 'authorization-text',
    },
    onChange(info) {
      if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
        console.log(info.file, info.fileList)
      }
      if (info.file.status === 'done') {
        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`)
      } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`)
      }
    },
    defaultFileList: [
      {
        uid: '1',
        name: 'xxx.png',
        status: 'done',
        response: 'Server Error 500', // custom error message to show
        url: 'http://www.baidu.com/xxx.png',
      },
  }
```

input:

```
 {formItem(
   props.form.getFieldDecorator('Image', {
     rules: [{ required: true }],
       })(
         <Upload {...uploadProps}>
           <Button>
             <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
           </Button>
         </Upload>,
        ),
        {
          label: 'Image',
        },
      )}
```

after `submit` I get a validation error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should't use `defaultFileList` along with `getFieldDecorator`.

`Antd` throws a warning about this

> warning: `defaultFileList` is invalid for `getFieldDecorator` will set
>   `fileList`, please use `option.initialValue` instead.

Move the defaultFileList array to initialValue field of getFieldDecorator options.

```
 {formItem(
   props.form.getFieldDecorator('Image', {
     rules: [{ required: true }],
     initialValue: [
      {
        uid: '1',
        name: 'xxx.png',
        status: 'done',
        response: 'Server Error 500', // custom error message to show
        url: 'http://www.baidu.com/xxx.png',
      },
      ]
       })(
         <Upload {...uploadProps}>
           <Button>
             <Icon type="upload" /> Click to Upload
           </Button>
         </Upload>,
        ),
        {
          label: 'Image',
        },
      )}
```